# how to find Duplicate records by comparing the previous records received in a table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a table

`seq_num      create_dt    col1  col2  is_load
    1      1/1/2014         A      B 
    2      2/1/2014         c      D

    3      3/1/2014         A      B`

Everyday data is loaded to the table through loader. I want to write a query where it should find the duplicate data in the current day record by comparing with the previous days records and update the column is_load = 'D'(as of Duplicate) if any duplicate record is found.

so the result should be like

```
`seq_num  create_dt   col1  col2  is_load
   1       1/1/2014     A     B            
   2       2/1/2014     C     D           
   3       3/1/2014     A     B          
   .          ....      .      .            
   .          ....      .      .
   11      11/3/2014     A     B      D    `
```

Thanks in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
update myTable m
set is_load = 'D'
where exists (select null
              from myTable
              where m.col1 = col1
                and m.col2 = col2
                and m.seq_num > seq_num);
```

This condition `m.seq_num > seq_num` helps to avoid setting up first entry to 'D'.

If it really matters you can easily change `seq_num` to `create_dt` but this can leave some entries which are loaded the same day.

Comment: thanks for your effort.  i have to find the duplicate records using create_date i mean i will be comparing the present date with the earlier one and see if the same record set is existing earlier or not if it does then i have to set is_load as D

Comment: ok, and does it mean that it is clear how to do it or should I additionally describe something else?

Comment: actually i want to find the duplicate records in the current day data and set the is_load column as 'D'. I do not want to update the is_load column for earlier day's records. What modification is needed in your code? For eg: if for today's date 11/3/2014  100 records are loaded to the table and if 36 records are found duplicate then for today's date 's 100 record, 36 records is_load column should be updated as D

Comment: just add `and create_dt between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate + 1)` into `exists` clause

Comment: still, m not able to get the duplicate records after adding the

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT seq_num, col1, 
    COUNT(col1) AS Num_Of_Occurrences
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY col1
    HAVING ( COUNT(col1) > 1 );
```